# awk is limited to only one line operations?

Tags: awk

Like in the subject. Let say I have a file which contains:

> *aaa A B C
>
> D E F 55
>
> *ccc A B C
>
> R E T 33

and I would know if it's possibe to make a statement if $1=="*aaa" then print $4 from next line. I know that one of the solutions could be to convent file to this output:

> *aaa A B C D E F 55
>
> *ccc A B C R E T 33

using "*" as line separator, but I would like to avoid this.

Regards,
lucas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a variable (called `primed` in the example) which is set if the match is found. the `next` statement reads the next line which is then printed if primed is set.

```
awk '{
if (primed) print $4; 
if ($1 == "*aaa") { primed=1; next } primed=0; }' file
```

Comment: how can I replace next statement if I'm looking for a value from not the next line but next+1 or the previous line?

Comment: store all lines in an awk array (actually a hash table). Feel free to upvote or accept answer :)